# Book of Irish fairy stories, including a story about a girl who rescues her father from selkies after he harms one

Tags: story-identification, books, audio-book, fairy-tales, folklore

When I was young I often listened to books on tape during car rides. One that I have fond memories of was an audiobook with a collection of Irish folk/fairy stories. I was hoping someone would know what the book is called so I can find it again.

I remember in one story a girl rescues her father who is a fishermen from some selkies. She discovers that her father actually harmed a selkie and stabbed it with a knife or harpoon or something of the sort, and she has to help save the selkie to get her father back. In another, a hunter catches a creature's tail and plans to make a soup with it but the creature keeps singing some song about "give me back my taily-o". I don't remember how that one ends. There are others that I've mostly forgotten, I know a wizard makes an appearance at one point.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s would you have listened to this?

Comment: David Holt did a recording of The Taily Bone; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95qVI6kTyeM which is the story about the tail soup. It's a fairly common American (note, not Irish) folk story that's been anthologised many times, also known as Taily-po or Tail-po - https://www.scaryforkids.com/tailypo/